# javascript drawImage() issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Currently having some issues with `drawImage();`. Namely it wont actually draw. I tried it out with `fillRect();` and it worked aswell as putting the `drawImage();` inside the the `onload` function aswell (which worked).

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 400;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var tileArray = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
];

var grassReady = false;
var grass = new Image();
grass.onload = function() {
        grassReady = true;
};
grass.src = "images/grass.png";

var sandReady = false;
var sand = new Image();
sand.onload = function() {
    sandReady = true;
};
sand.src = "images/sand.png";

var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

if(grassReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(grass, posX, posY);
}
```

Any pointers as to why this is would be greatly appreciated and I appologize in advance if messed up the code section in anyway. I went through other similar posts and coulden't find a solution that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Suman Bogati correctly says, you must wait for your images to load before using them in drawImage.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jGPGj/

[image]

Here's an image loader that preloads all images and then calls the start() function where you can use drawImage because all the images are fully loaded.

```
var imageURLs=[];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
imageURLs.push("images/grass.png");
imageURLs.push("images/sand.png");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

    // grass.png is in imgs[0]
    // sand.png is in imgs[1]

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch markE and especially for going to such length! Learned alot more than I asked for which is always appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This statement `ctx.drawImage();` should be inside the `grass.onload = function() {}` function, something like

```
grass.onload = function() {
     ctx.drawImage(grass, posX, posY);
}
```

If you define `drawImage()` outside the `grass.onload()` function, then that statment would executed first, so at that point `grassReady` is false, So the condition is not satisfied.

Bascially it's related to asynchronous concept.

Your code is running into order

**1) First**

```
var grassReady = false;

if(grassReady) {
    //grassReady is false, this condition is not satisfied
    ctx.drawImage(grass, posX, posY);
}
```

**2) Second**

```
grass.onload = function() {
     grassReady = true;
};
```